# YADCF select - with custom options

Tags: datatables, jquery-select2, yadcf

Have a table with some data loaded from server by provised ajax to DataTable, also have yadcf for filtering on server side. In one of columns i have select2 box, in what i want see only predefined (loaded from server) options (in example on jsfiddle it is `opt` variable), but options in select2 contains also data from column. How i can disable adding column data, and stay only loaded from server options?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/6ssh8mg4/
```

code:

```
 var opts = [{id:0, text:"Some 1"},{id:1, text:"Some 2"}];
 var table = $("#docTable").DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: false,
            paging: true,
            ordering: true,
            deferRender: true,
            pageLength: 10,
            lengthMenu: [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, "All"]],
            columns: [
               { "data": "Identifier", className: "nowrap" },
               { "data": "Name" },
            ]
 });

yadcf.init(table, [
  { column_number: 0, filter_type: "text", style_class: "form_control", filter_default_label: "" },
  {
    column_number: 1, filter_type: "select", select_type: "select2", filter_default_label: "",
    select_type_options: {
      data: opts,
      width: '180px',
      dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    }
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [data](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/0fef198b9bb8193ef517ca690ac5f322cc9f0ad8/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L47) attribute (in your case with data/label properties), read the docs

Here is a working sample

```
var opts = [{value:0, label:"Some 1"},{value:1, label:"Some 2"}];
var table = $("#docTable").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    paging: true,
    ordering: true,
    deferRender: true,
    pageLength: 10,
    lengthMenu: [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, "All"]],
    columns: [
       { "data": "Identifier", className: "nowrap" },
       { "data": "Name" },
    ]
 });

yadcf.init(table, [
    { 
    column_number: 0, filter_type: "text", style_class: "form_control", filter_default_label: "" },
    {
        data: opts,
        column_number: 1, filter_type: "select", select_type: "select2", filter_default_label: "",
        select_type_options: {
            width: '180px',
            dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        }
    },
]);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ssh8mg4/1/)